# Open Layers 3 detect if WMS feed hasn't worked

Tags: openlayers-3, wms

I have an Open Layers 3 implementation which reads data from a WMS data feed.

I've noticed that if the WMS data feed goes down I don't get any errors on the browser side, it just doesn't receive any layers.

Is there a way in Open Layers 3 to detect if a WMS call returns nothing?

I have tried the experimental function `getState()`, but this always returns **ready** even on bad WMS calls.

Comment: How about you try sending a WMS `GetCapabilities` request ?  If you get a response, then your server's fine.  Otherwise, you could react accordingly.  Thoughts ?

Comment: This was a thought I had as well.  I was hoping there may be a more direct solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

I built a function to get layers data from GeoServer via Ajax and parse the response, maybe you could add the "error" config to alert the user.

```
function getDataFromGeoServer(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.1.0&request=GetCapabilities",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            var parser = new ol.format.WMSCapabilities();
            var result = parser.read(response);

            var layersArray = result.Capability.Layer.Layer;
            layersNameArray = [];

            for(i=0;i<layersArray.length;i++){
                layersNameArray.push(layersArray[i].Name)
            }

            callback(layersNameArray);

        }
        error: function() {
            /////// ADD ERROR CONFIG
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes that looks useful, I'll try it out